# Where string will create object in java when we did concat operation?

Tags: java, string

I wrote the following;

```
String str1 = new String("railway"); // line 1
String str2 = str1.concat("station"); // line 2
```

When line 1 executes string will create objects in scp and heap.

What about the line 2 statement? In this case also it creates in scp and heap?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it create a new string?

Comment: I believe even the scp is in heap, as of Java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"railway" and "station" will be in Constant Pool.

str1 and str2 will be in heap.